# VPN for specific UDP ports?

Tags: vpn, ping, udp

My ping to DotA 2 servers (online video game) is very poor in afternoon hours. My ping usually go as high as 300ms or even more.

I tried to use OpenVPN with my dedicated server my ping decreased to about 80ms.

I'd like to route all game traffic through this server but not any other traffic though. How can I accomplish this?

I tried to use Proxifier or ProxyCap with SSH tunnel, but it didn't work unfortunately as the game uses UDP ports of 27015-27040 to communicate with the servers.

Comment: Do you know the IP address of the DotA servers?

Comment: Ignore the close vote, was testing something and accidentally hit enter. o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to route traffic is by IP address.  Find out the IP addresses of the DotA servers that you commonly access, and add routes to your gaming machine (assuming Windows) to your OpenVPN server private IP.  In a command prompt with Administrator privileges:

```
route add <dota server ip> mask 255.255.255.255 <openvpn server private ip>
```

If you use the -p parameter it will make it permanent (survives a reboot).

If it isn't clear what the server IP address is, then you can route via the openvpn interface instead.

This command

```
netsh interfaces ipv4 show interfaces
```

will provide a list of interfaces in your machine.  One of these is the openvpn tun/tap interface.  Note its index (the idx) field.

Then add the route with the netsh command instead:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add route prefix=<dota ip address>/32 interface=<idx> store=active
```

Change `store=active1` to `store=persistant` to get it to survive a reboot.

This will direct any traffic destined for the dota server to the openvpn box.

Comment: This assumes that the openvpn connection is on a different machine to your gaming machine, as you refer to your "dedicated openvpn server".  If this is misunderstood, then the princible remains the same, we just need to alter the routing.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! Yes, OpenVPN server is not on my gaming machine. Following your tutorial should I substitude <open vpn server ip> with the remote IP address of OpenVPN server or local IP that OpenVPN server assign me? Furthermore, can I set IP ranges of DotA servers so I don't have to add them one by one? And last question what if I add routing to a server on route that is cause of my issue, would that work?

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I am not clear on what you asking, but there isn't much you can do with routing at the remote end that will help this situation.  I have updated the queston to clarify which IP address you need to use on the route statement